# How do I configure database connection pooling in Tomcat and obtain a connection in my servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jndi

I am new to web development using Java Servlets/JSP. If I understand correctly, I should be able to configure a container level data source  in tomcat, and obtain a connection in my servlet code by calling the getConnection() method.

What is the process for implementing a datasource and connection pool?  I am using Oracle XE as the database and Tomcat as the server.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728654/how-to-use-connection-pool-with-tomcat-6-and-mysql